# Pandas conditionaly return value at corresponding position in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and programming in general.

I am trying to figure out how to return a comma separated value at the corresponding position within a different column in pandas and store this output in a new column. See my example below

```
key_list = [cat, dog, pig]

A           B
---------------------
1           cat
1, 2        dog, cat
1, 2, 3     pig, dog, cat
```

I want an output which is the following:

```
A           B          cat_result      dog_result     pig_result 
----------------------------------------------------------------
1           cat            1              NAN           NAN
6, 2        dog, cat       2              6             NAN
8, 3, 1     pig, dog, cat  1              3              8
```

So, I would like to be able to check for the presence of the keys (a, b or c) in column B, then if it is present, return the value in column A that is in the corresponding comma separated value within that cell.

So far I have this:

```
for key in key_list:
    df["{}_result".format{key}] = df.apply(lambda _: int(key in _.B), axis=1)
```

Which will create a new column for each key_result and then give a 1 if the key is present within B or a 0 if not. Not sure where to go from here or if this is the right approach. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `np.core.defchararray.split` in a `lambda` to help split the column's values.  I could have used `pd.Series.str.split`, But I opted for this.

Then I use the `lambda` and iterate through row by row to create a list of dictionaries.  That list of dictionaries can then be passed to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor.

Finally, I use `join` to attach the original dataframe.

```
s = lambda x: np.core.defchararray.split(x.values.astype(str), ', ')
df.join(
    pd.DataFrame(
        [dict(zip(*t)) for t in zip(s(df.B), s(df.A))]
    ).add_suffix('_result')
)

         A              B cat_result dog_result pig_result
0        1            cat          1        NaN        NaN
1     6, 2       dog, cat          2          6        NaN
2  8, 3, 1  pig, dog, cat          1          3          8
```

Comment: That's fantastic, I'm really sorry but in my simplification of the problem I reduced the keys to be single letters, is there a way to adapt this for whole phrases e.g. key_list = [cat, dog, pig] rather than key_list = [a, b, c]? I will update to add in originlal Q.

Comment: Works the same either way.